# How to fold/expand treeview in vim (built-in netrw)?

Tags: vim, treeview, netrw

I like to use vim's built-in netrw plugin to list files of project. Sometimes when I expand a folder to see its content I need to fold it back and go to the next folder. For example, at the right side of the screen I want to fold `components` folder and easily go to `elementcss`.

[image]

Is it possible?

**UPDATE**

I need to fold when my cursor inside of `components` folder. Because I can just press enter to fold it.

Answer (score 5):

I'm assuming that you're using netrw's tree listing mode: with the cursor atop a directory name, [return] will toggle between displaying the directory's contents and not doing so.

The  (shift+return) mapping, present since netrw v151 (Mar '14) will also do what you're asking for (squeeze the parent directory).  Its restricted to use with gvim since most terminals won't pass a shift-return along to vim.

Comment: I know it, but I want to fold parent directory, hence `elementcss`, not the `templates`.

Answer (score 0):

I also needed to collapse a parent folder, so I created this function and mapped it to the x key.

```
" map x key to collapse parent folder
autocmd FileType netrw nmap <buffer> x :call NetrwCollapse()<CR>

function! NetrwCollapse()
    redir => cnt
        silent .s/|//gn
    redir END
    let lvl = substitute(cnt, '\n', '', '')[0:0] - 1
    exec '?^\(| \)\{' . lvl . '\}\w'
    exec "normal \<CR>"
endfunction
```

Edit: I have changed the mapping to say `autocmd FileType` instead of `autocmd filetype` because some systems require the capitalization.

Edit2: Changed the mapping to only call `<CR>` once. Then added a normal `<CR>` to the end of the function, so it is called from there. Works better on newer systems.

Comment: This overrides the default mapping for `x` for opening html, jpeg, etc. files (`:help netrw-x`)